# How to type enum and object to have same properties React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, enums

i have an enum:

```
enum INFO_CODES {
goToInit = 'goToInit',
lockIp = 'lockIp',
```

}

and i want to create an object(or enum also) with the same properties (only goToInit and lockIp)

```
const SOME_OBJ = {
goToInit: function, //here i need function
lockIp: function,//here i need function
someProp:function //here i need mistake,can create only like in 
INFO_CODES props.
```

}

Comment: What you're trying to do is unclear. Do you want properties in `SOME_OBJ` to have the same signature (parameters and return type) as another function? Or do you want the properties to be _exactly_ a specific value of that enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) and just use the `enum` as the first generic parameter for the key and then whatever function type you want to have next.

```js
enum INFO_CODES {
  goToInit = 'goToInit',
  lockIp = 'lockIp',
}

type result = Record<INFO_CODES, () => void>;

const test: result = {
  goToInit: () => console.log("test"),
  lockIp: () => console.log("lockIp"),
}
```